# Replace table with a single row of NEW for a query

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger

In my trigger procedure for inserts to the `X` table, I want to check what will the result of a certain query be, if table `X` only included a single row with currently inserted values (`NEW`).

I tried the following in the procedure (simplified code):

```
WITH X AS (SELECT * FROM NEW)
SELECT * FROM X WHERE …some_conditions…
```

…but the `SELECT * FROM NEW` is invalid.

I can't find any way to "cast" `NEW` to a table. 
Is it even possible?

Comment: `new` is a single row (at least if you have a row level trigger) so it's not a table and thus you can't select "FROM" it

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yeah, but I figured there must be a way to create a temporary static table since I have all the info I need (in NEW). Can't find that way though.

Comment: Why don't you just use the fields of the row record directly? e.g. if that "some conditions" is `where some_column = 42` you can use `if new.some_column = 42 ...` instead

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Because the query is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `SELECT * FROM (VALUES(NEW.*)) AS my_alias;`

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE test_trig_new (
 id int4 NULL,
 val text NULL,
 val2 text NULL
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trig_test_new()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
  l_row test_trig_new%rowtype;
BEGIN
  SELECT * INTO l_row FROM (VALUES(NEW.*)) AS a;
  RAISE NOTICE 'val2 %, record %', l_row.val2, l_row;
  RETURN NEW;
END
$function$
;

CREATE TRIGGER trig_test_new
BEFORE INSERT ON test_trig_new
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trig_test_new();

INSERT INTO test_trig_new VALUES (55, 'test55', 'test66423');

--raises NOTICE: val2 test66423, record (55,test55,test66423)
```

Comment: Sure, then I have the table-like interface in a variable, but I can't use that variable in a query as if it was a table. Or can I?
EDIT: Actually it's not even table-like, because it's only one row - this way I am back to square one with `l_row` instead of `OLD`.

Comment: You are inserting more than one row with single query and want trigger to have access to all changes done by query?

Comment: No, only the current row. I just want to be able to treat this one record as a regular table (with only 1 row) in a query. Like in my code, I define "table-like" `X` and then use it in a query as if it was a table.

Comment: Maybe I'm having an XY problem here - I just think that it must be possible to somehow make a table-like temporary alias (like `X` in my example), since I already have all the data I want that table to have.